# Regex to extract data located within square brackets [...]

Tags: java, regex

I need to find regex for string represent date `[07/Mar/2014:22:12:28 -0800]` from mentioned line:

**`64.242.88.10` – – `[07/Mar/2014:22:12:28 -0800]` “GET /twiki/bin/attach/TWiki/WebSearch HTTP/1.1” 401 12846**

Comment: it is not correct.

Comment: Updated the solution.

Comment: Please [select the below answer as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
\[[0-9]{1,2}\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} -[0-9]{4}]
```

Short version(greedy) since it is enclosed by `[ ]`:

```
\[.*]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your string doesn't have any other content in square braces besides this, then:

```
\[.*?]
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uO7WKY/1)

---

**Details**

- `\[` - opening bracket (escaped because `[` is a meta-character)
- `.*?` - non-greedy match-all
- `]` - closing bracket (doesn't need escaping)

---

When adapting for use in a Java program, you'll need to escape the backslash too.:

```
Pattern.compile("\\[.*?]");
```

Comment: @bhansa The correctness of this solution heavily depends on OP's use case.

Comment: @COLDSPEED while putting provided regex \\[.*?] in Pattern logPattern = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?]");. getting error on this line. i believe that something is missing as per provided regex.

Comment: @aj0007 You missed the leading `\ `.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks. it is working. but need to add one more backslash as you provided regex. i.e \\\[.*?]